# Transport Subscriber's data over CAN to Non-ROS computer

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello ROS users,

I want to use a [Non-ROS computer](http://www.terasoft.com.tw/english/htm/pd-mbox1.html) as the controller to receive the data from the ROS computer.

To specify my question : I have a lidar(sick tim 561) and  I use my ROS computer(ubuntu 14.04 LTS with ROS Jade and a CAN card) to launch it successfully. After that, I have read the "Publisher and Subscriber" tutorials because I need use a subscriber to subscribe the lidar's scan topic and then transport the data to Non-ROS computer over the CAN-bus. But when I search the CAN-bus for the ROS for my ROS Jade version, I found [this](http://wiki.ros.org/cob_generic_can) and without the JADE version. Does anyone know the CAN-bus communication for Jade? If there is the Jade version, could you direct me which part is I need? Thanks in advanced.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223375/transport-subscriber%27s-data-over-can-to-non-ros-computer/) by [Terry Su](https://answers.ros.org/users/25230/terry-su/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2016-01-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2016-01-02**:
Have you tried to use the indigo version? Indigo and Jade are not that different so I bet that the indigo version is still working.

**Comment by [Terry Su](https://answers.ros.org/users/25230/terry-su/) on 2016-01-02**:
@NEngelhard, Thank for your information, I will try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Don't.

Lidar data typically has a pretty high data rate 1-10Mbit, and CAN typically has data rates of 1Mbit and below, with fairly high overhead (50% or more). From bandwidth alone, sending lidar data over a CAN bus will be difficult.

In addition, CAN limits the maximum packet size to 8 bytes, and lidar scans are usually much larger than that (hundreds of bytes to hundreds of kilobytes). The amount of fragmentation that you'll have to do to make that work will be problematic at best.

Also of note, most of the CAN packages that I've seen for ROS provide a C++ API that wraps the native linux or proprietary CAN API; they don't provide a magic ROS-to-CAN bridge. If you do get the package you've found to work, you'll still need to do the hard work yourself.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-01-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Terry Su](https://answers.ros.org/users/25230/terry-su/) on 2016-01-03**:
Thanks you for your remind really! If I don't have your remind, maybe I will spend a lot of time on it.